# Running Kafka ACL Commands fail

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, acl, jaas

I am trying to run any kafka acl commands from adding, deleting, and list. An example command is:

> ../bin/kafka-acls.sh --authorizer-properties
>   zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 --add --allow-principal User:demouser
>   --operation Create --operation Describe  --topic demo-topic

But I always get the error:

```
Error while executing ACL command: Exception while loading Zookeeper JAAS login context 'Client'
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Exception while loading Zookeeper JAAS login context 'Client'
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.JaasUtils.isZkSecurityEnabled(JaasUtils.java:45)
    at kafka.admin.AclCommand$AuthorizerService.withAuthorizer(AclCommand.scala:197)
    at kafka.admin.AclCommand$AuthorizerService.addAcls(AclCommand.scala:221)
    at kafka.admin.AclCommand$.main(AclCommand.scala:70)
    at kafka.admin.AclCommand.main(AclCommand.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: java.io.IOException: /remote/sde108/kafka/kafka/config/config.conf (No such file or directory)
    at sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.<init>(ConfigFile.java:137)
    at sun.security.provider.ConfigFile.<init>(ConfigFile.java:102)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at javax.security.auth.login.Configuration$2.run(Configuration.java:255)
    at javax.security.auth.login.Configuration$2.run(Configuration.java:247)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.login.Configuration.getConfiguration(Configuration.java:246)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.JaasUtils.isZkSecurityEnabled(JaasUtils.java:42)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: /remote/sde108/kafka/kafka/config/config.conf (No such file or directory)
    at sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.ioException(ConfigFile.java:666)
    at sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.init(ConfigFile.java:262)
    at sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.<init>(ConfigFile.java:135)
    ... 15 more
```

Based on my search, there is no file called config.conf in the kafka or zookeeper installation. Did anyone encounter a similar problem or the same one and knows how to fix it?

Comment: It assume you've defined an environment variable that loads that file. Can you please run `env | grep KAFKA`? Basically, the JAAS config can point anywhere, not files that Kafka provides

Comment: Got it cricket_007. found out that KAFKA_OPTS was pointing to that weird file. just changed it to look at my kafka_server_jaas.conf file and that fixed it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving comment to answer.

Based on the error, you've loaded a JAAS file somehow.

These could be set up within environment variables, and you could find that like `env | grep KAFKA`